# Trigger activity when taping on an element in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I prepared a GridView that has 6 images, every image has to launch an Activity when i tap on it.
How to make that in GridView?
Thank you very much.
Code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.stock, R.drawable.rouge,
            R.drawable.stock, R.drawable.rouge,
            R.drawable.stock, R.drawable.rouge,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`View#setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29)

```
imageView.setOnCLickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //start Activity here
    }
});
```

Comment: And how to make that to every image showen in GridView ? imageView variable contains all the 6 images. How to make it one by one ?